# What to do about a user excessively posting useless comments?

Tags: discussion, new-users, comments, users, spam

A user (who's not particularly new, yet I'd never noticed him until about a week ago) has been posting excessive comments. I don't mean excessive comments like [mine here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/76604/61563), I mean excessive comments along the lines of...

- > Whoa, how is this even possible?
- > Is this ever going to end?????
- > You got my name right!!!1!!1!11! :D       (x5)

These comments in small numbers don't seem to be a problem. But when a user begins commenting on more or less every post in a thread, it gets a little obnoxious. When a user has something to say - not constructive, not destructive, just noise - about 50% of the answers he sees, I don't think anyone appreciates it.

I've asked this user to stop, and I was ignored. I won't link to his profile for obvious reasons. He has posted 80 comments in the last two days, ten of which I noticed without seeking them out.

This behavior clearly doesn't warrant a ban/suspension/privilege-revoke, so what can be done?

Comment: `Telling someone that their exceptional answer is wonderfully written, or has never been done before, or is the greatest thing they've ever seen on the site, is something to be encouraged.` - no, [it's not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Mithrandir Oh, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flag the comments as "no longer needed" as you see them. If they're really getting out of hand, flag them for moderator attention with details about how this is becoming a frequent problem with the users. The moderators will take action as they see necessary.

For what it's worth, spamming useless comments is grounds for a suspension in my opinion.

Comment: Flags, certainly. Too bad *not constructive* isn't an option anymore. These comments were never *needed* in the first place, and *no longer needed* doesn't cast mod flags warning about X flags in Y days.

Comment: @Dennis Why is not constructive no longer an option?  Is this only our site or all sites?

Comment: @WheatWizard [Drop “not constructive”, combine “noisy”, reword “rude” and “other” comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298420/170332)

Comment: @Dennis `The middle flag - "no longer needed" - is new, and is intended to cover all of "too chatty", "obsolete", and the non-abusive uses of "not constructive".`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It doesn't cover them though.

Comment: Hmm, I've now got about 35 `helpful` flags that got comments deleted. How long will it be until the system does something about his commenting privilege?

Comment: @MDXF I don't know if the system will do anything automatically, but the moderators will if they deem it necessary.